# PhoneGap - How to get the last URL used from my phonegap application?

Tags: android, browser, cordova, push-notification

I am doing the GCM application using phonegap. I am able to get the push notification. Once the push notification appears in my notification bar, on click of notification bar I need to get the last used URL which is used from my app. Also I need to open that last used URL in the browser or webview. So how to get the last used URL which is used from my application.

Answer (score 1):

If you need get this info from your application, you can try to use window.history object.

Comment: Can you please explain in detail.

Comment: if you want go back in your browser/webview, you can run window.history.back() or window.history.go(-1)

Comment: will this give the last used url from which is used from the application.